# How to update Python 3 installed through the Microsoft store without reinstalling a new version?

Tags: installation, python, windows-store-app, windows-store, windows-terminal

I installed Python 3.10 through the Microsoft Store and used to launch my scripts calling in python as such: `python <path to script>.py`.

Python 3.11 just launched and now that I type `python` in the Terminal Window, this opens the relevant Python
[Python 3.11 page from the MS Store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LBrw.png).
There, I see no options to update. I can only do a fresh install of the software. But I would like to keep all the installed packages so do you guys know of a way to update the current version instead?

Comment: If in the Store window you click your account icon, then select Settings, under App updates, is "Update apps automatically" set to On?

Comment: hi, the thing is that Python 3.10 and 3.11 are two different apps in the MS Store

Comment: You are tracking that performing an upgrade to Python would essentially reinstall Python. Have you considered using [winget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/winget/) to install Python. If typing python offers you to install Python, it means Python is not installed, or the alias is pointing to a Python environment that no longer exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to set the Microsoft Store to automatically window you click
your account icon, then select Settings, under App updates, and set
"Update apps automatically" set to On.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work for Python, where the project has
chosen to publish each version as a separate package, so that real
update is impossible. If you have made modifications to the
installation, you will need to repeat them for each new version.

It would be better to download and install python from
[python.org](https://www.python.org/)
and not from the Microsoft Store.
The Store version is only the basic version, while the full download
has more contents.

See the instructions at
[Python Download and Installation Instructions](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Epattis/common/handouts/pythoneclipsejava/python.html).
When installing a new version over an old one you will have the
two options: "Install Now" or "Upgrade Now".

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Store is not a great way to keep your software up-to-date, especially when the vendor decides to release separate versions as different apps.

The alternative would be to use a real package manager, few of which exist for Windows:

- [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/), which has a virtual `python` [package](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/python) that lets you always update to the latest version. If you instead want to keep ugrading only `3.x` versions (in case Python 4 comes out), you can also use [this](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/python312) package directly instead.
- [scoop](https://scoop.sh/) that can install latest Python with `scoop install python`. This installs the [package](https://github.com/ScoopInstaller/Main/blob/master/bucket/python.json) from main bucket.
- [winget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/winget/), which is available in Windows 10/11 by default. It can install latest Python 3 in theory, but there are [reported issues](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-pkgs/issues/85695) with that. Unlike in Choco and scoop, new versions are also manually added, while that's automated in previous tools.

To summarize, I'd recommend Chocolatey here (and not only here), as you have the most control with it.